# ControlDesigner Class (C# WinForms)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

I'm on [`ControlDesigner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.controldesigner.aspx) trying to have a play around with it and it tells me to add a reference to `System.Design` to compile it **but** `System.Design` does not exist.

And my project (copied directly from the page above) will not compile.

I have Windows 7 Home Premium, .NET 4 / VS 2010 Express (if that matters at all).

Have any of you had trouble finding this reference? Do you know where I can find it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your project is targeting the .NET Framework Client Profile, which does not include `System.Design`.

Visual Studio 2010 does this by default for all new projects. To make an existing project target the full version of the Framework, open your project's Properties window and select ".NET Framework 4.0" from the combo box labeled "Target framework".

[image]

Once you've done that, you will be able to add the reference using the "Add References" dialog.

Comment: Thanks, @Cody Gray! Now I just gotta figure out what it does ;p :)

Comment: @Lucifer: This is a common problem. There are lots of similar questions here on SO about `System.Web`, which is another assembly not included in the Client Profile. As has been suggested in those other answers, there's very little reason not to target the full version of the Framework, and VS probably should do this by default. It's only about 18% larger for version 4.0; really just a drop in the bucket. But fair warning: the functionality provided by the `System.Design` class is one of the most complicated things you'll see in the Framework. Don't feel bad if it looks like black magic.